# Selenium Java code for Listbox selection works on Chrome and IE, but not Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am working on a public site: 
http://preview.harriscountyfws.org/

I am trying to do something simple:
Select an option from a dropdown.

The very same code that works on IE and Chrome, fails on Firefox.  No error is generated.  It just doesn't pick the right option ("Channel Status") from the Site Type Dropdown.

Any help on this appreciated!

```
WebElement listbox_element2, we2;
        String ariaOwns = "siteType_listbox";
        String searchText2 = "Channel Status";


    listbox_element2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[aria-owns='" + ariaOwns + "']"));
    listbox_element2.click();
    Sleep(2000);
    we2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='" + searchText2 + "']"));
    if (we2 != null) {
        we2.click();
    }`
```

Comment: can you show some html? It will make it easier to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to introduce an explicit wait while running test on firefox browser and then print all the drop down options as part of debugging. By making a use of **selectByValue(value)** method, you can select an item from drop list.

```
WebElement mySelectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("mySelect"));
Select dropdown= new Select(mySelectElement);
List options = dropdown.getOptions();
for (WebElement option : options) {
System.out.println(option.getText()); //output "option1", "option2", "option3"
}
```